# Random model being shown in Swagger UI - A different model is actually mentioned in thepython api files

Tags: flask, swagger, swagger-ui, flask-restx

I am using flask-restx

Given the code below , I expect to see create_prompt_model in the Swagger UI for POST/prompts/create, but I see update_prompt_model in the Swagger UI

[Swagger UI screenshot for POST/prompts/create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuNTa.png)

My code for the prompts namesppce that I am adding to my api.py:

```
  
from uuid import uuid4
from flask import jsonify, request
from flask_restx import Resource, Namespace, fields, reqparse
from datastore.azure_cosmosdb.store import CosmosDb
import os
import yaml
from prompts.service import PromptsService

prompts_namespace = Namespace('prompts', description='Prompts CRUD')


AZURE_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT = os.getenv("AZURE_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT")
AZURE_COSMOS_DB_KEY = os.getenv("AZURE_COSMOS_DB_KEY")

with open(r'config/config.yml', 'r') as f:
    all_configs = yaml.safe_load(f)

space = all_configs['space']
cosmos_db_name = all_configs["cosmos_db"]["DB_NAME"]
container_name = all_configs["prompt_store"]["CONTAINER_NAME"]


prompt_store_config = {"DB_NAME": cosmos_db_name,
                       "CONTAINER_NAME":container_name,
                       "URL":AZURE_COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT,
                       "KEY":AZURE_COSMOS_DB_KEY}


prompts_store = CosmosDb(config=prompt_store_config)
prompt_service = PromptsService(db=prompts_store)


get_query_model = prompts_namespace.model('GetQuery', {
    'filters': fields.String(description='Query values', required=True)
})

create_prompt_model = prompts_namespace.model('Prompts', {
    'description': fields.String(description='Desc of prompt', required=True),
    'prompt_set': fields.Raw(description='Dictionary consisting of the keys short_prompt and long_prompt', required=True)
})

update_prompt_model = prompts_namespace.model('Prompts', {
    'root_prompt_id': fields.String(description='The id of the root prompt for which we need to create a new version', required=True),
    'description': fields.String(description='Desc of prompt', required=False),
    'updated_prompt_set': fields.Raw(description='Dictionary consisting of the keys short_prompt and long_prompt', required=True)
})



@prompts_namespace.route('/<string:prompt_id>')
class Prompt(Resource):
    @prompts_namespace.doc(params={'prompt_id':'id of the prompt'})    
    def get(self,prompt_id): 
        """
        get a prompt set with provided prompt_id

        Parameters
        ----------
       prompt_id: id of the prompt set 

        Returns
        -------
        A prompt set with the provided prompt_id
        """

        result = prompt_service.get(prompt_id)
        print(result)

        return jsonify(result)
    
@prompts_namespace.route('/create')
class CreatePrompt(Resource):
    @prompts_namespace.expect(create_prompt_model)
    def post(self):
        """
        Upserts an item (consisting of the given prompt set and description) in the prompt store

        Parameters
        ---------
        prompt_set: A dictionary consisting of the Long and short prompt templates
        description:  Description of the prompt set

        Returns
        -------
        id of the prompt upserted in the the prompt store

        """
        body = request.json
        description = body['description']
        prompt_set = body['prompt_set']
        prompt_id  = prompt_service.create(prompt_set,description)
        return prompt_id
    
@prompts_namespace.route('/update')
class UpdatePrompt(Resource):
    @prompts_namespace.expect(update_prompt_model)
    def post(self):
        """
        Given an existing prompt id, Create a new prompt set with  provided description and updated_prompt_set.
        The version of this newly created prompt set will be (latest version among all the prompt sets with the specified prompt id) + 1 

        Parameters
        ----------
        root_prompt_id: The id of the root prompt for which we need to create a new version
        description: description of the prompt set
        updated_prompt_set: updated prompt set to be created for the descripiton
    
        Returns
        -------
        message:tells whether the updated happened

        """

        body = request.json
        description = body.get('description')
        updated_prompt_set = body.get('updated_prompt_set')
        root_prompt_id = body.get('root_prompt_id')
        return prompt_service.update(root_prompt_id=root_prompt_id,
                                     description=description, 
                                     updated_prompt_set=updated_prompt_set)
```

I expect to see create_prompt_model in the Swagger UI for POST/prompts/create, but I see update_prompt_model in the Swagger UI